Evitar que Here Maps reposicione y amplíe el mapa al calcular una ruta
estoy programando una aplicación similar a Uber o Cabify, cuando compartes tu ubicación o ruta, para que las personas a las que se la envías puedan ver la ruta en tiempo real.
No he usado Here para esto, más que nada lo he usado para mostrar ubicaciones estáticas y demás, he estado programando esto en ReactJS y Python, seguí la instrucción Here en ReactJS (que es muy pequeña) y lo que hago es que cuando detecto un cambio en las coordenadas del vehículo y recalculo la ruta. No sé si hay una forma mejor de hacerlo o más óptima, pero lo hago así porque necesito calcular el tiempo estimado y la API de Routing me lo da.
El problema es que cada vez que recalcula la ruta centra el mapa y lo mueve a una ubicación, pero no quiero que haga eso, solo mueva los puntos y listo, no he encontrado documentación para eso. solo una función getViewModel().setLookAtData, que mueve el mapa, pero no funciona, intenté guardar el zoom y la posición anterior y cargarlo después de calcular la ruta, pero no me funciona, ¿Qué podría hacer?
Grabé un video que creo que ejemplifica mejor el problema, gracias.
Video
Working with React


      var zoom = map.getZoom();
      var center = map.getCenter();
      const sections = response.routes[0].sections;
      for (const section of sections) {
        var horaestimada = segundosAHorasMinutos(section.travelSummary.duration);
        console.log(`Duración del viaje: ${horaestimada}`);
        dispatch(setETA(horaestimada));
      }
      const lineStrings = [];
      sections.forEach((section) => {
          // convert Flexible Polyline encoded string to geometry
          lineStrings.push(H.geo.LineString.fromFlexiblePolyline(section.polyline));
      });
      const multiLineString = new H.geo.MultiLineString(lineStrings);
      const bounds = multiLineString.getBoundingBox();

      // Create the polyline for the route
      const routePolyline = new H.map.Polyline(multiLineString, {
          style: {
              lineWidth: 5
          }
      });

      // Remove all the previous map objects, if any
      map.removeObjects(map.getObjects());
      // Add the polyline to the map
      var htmlbody
      for (const tripulante of tripulacion) {
        htmlbody = '<p class="body2Text"> <span> '+tripulante.cargo+': </span> ' + tripulante.nombre+ ' - ' + tripulante.documento+'</p>';
      }
      map.addObject(routePolyline);
      map.addObjects([
          // Add a marker for the user
          new H.map.Marker(start, {
              icon: getMarkerIcon(estado),
              data: {
                message: '<div class="body2Title" style="width: 300px;"><p>'+nombre+'</p><hr style="margin-top: 0px;"></span>' + htmlbody,
                idmarcador: 'xd',
                // Puedes agregar más propiedades personalizadas aquí
              }
          }),
          // Add a marker for the selected restaurant
          new H.map.Marker(destination, {
              icon: getMarkerIcon(null),
              data: {
                message: '<div class="body2Title" style="width: 300px;"><p> Destino </p><hr style="margin-top: 0px;"></span>',
                idmarcador: 'xd',
                // Puedes agregar más propiedades personalizadas aquí
              }
          })
      ]);



Intenté guardar el zoom y la posición anteriores y cargarlos después de calcular la ruta, pero no me funciona.
También intenté mantener la posición del mapa así: map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({bounds: map.getViewModel().getLookAtData().bounds}, true);

OK ya encontre el problema, esta función que solo es para centrar el mapa cuando se pulsa un botón, se activaba cuando re calculaba ruta:
useEffect(() => {
  if (map.current && ubicarMovil) {
    // Actualiza la ubicación del mapa
    map.current.setCenter({ lat: ubicarMovil.lat, lng: ubicarMovil.lng });
  }
}, [ubicarMovil]); // Observa las coordenadas

Simplemente le añadí un parametro de validación más, que solo se activara al pulsar el botón, soy nuevo en ReactJS
useEffect(() => {
  if (map.current && ubicarMovil && shouldUpdateMap) {
    // Actualiza la ubicación del mapa
    map.current.setCenter({ lat: ubicarMovil.lat, lng: ubicarMovil.lng });
  }
}, [ubicarMovil, shouldUpdateMap]); // Observa las coordenadas

